# Detect and Log copy/paste/delete/cut operations in File Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, explorer

I want to detect and log to file Explorer operations such as copy/cut/delete/paste.

I have read about [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I also noticed it has some issues since there is no copy/cut events available which can be confusing with whatever I want to do.

> The operating system and FileSystemWatcher object interpret a cut-and-paste action or a move action as a rename action for a folder and its contents. If you cut and paste a folder with files into a folder being watched, the FileSystemWatcher object reports only the folder as new, but not its contents because they are essentially only renamed.

`FileSystemWatcher` is hooking  the *create file* and *delete file* events to the *changed* and *renamed* events which can't really help me to determine if it was made by the user or some another process. Furthermore I cannot be 100% sure what happened to the file whether it was copied or cut etc.

I also need to keep track of the locations "from/to" and the name of file.

Is there some alternative to the `FileSystemWatcher` that can distinguish between these actions?

Comment: This question [is being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223356/why-is-this-question-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I think the `FileSystemWatcher` would be of use in this scenario. You could use the `Changed` event, which occurs when a file or directory is changed - like a copy/paste action.

See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this event, and the class itself. Note that there are other events that you can also use for the delete/cut actions.

The events use the `FileSystemEventArgs` which contains properties for `FullPath` and `Name`.

Comment: In the MSDN sample they want me to specify the directory , where the watcher should watch, how can I make it global ? for every event in every directory ?

Comment: If you want it to be global for the entire disk, you could set the directory to C:\ or whatever the root directory is. Then on the FileSystemWatcher object you created, set the IncludeSubdirectories property to true and this will monitor all subdirectories.

Comment: I really trying to make it work :) , well I hope the onChange event will really do the work . thanks

Comment: Monitoring the entire C:\ drive (or the operating system hard disk) would likely fire quite a lot of events due to the OS file operations. So this should be something to consider.

Comment: I finally done it :) , and yes as I  thought i fires milliard events per second are done by operating system and not by user :(
but I interested in user made operations can I somehow filter that ?

Comment: also I cant know whether it was copied or pasted , it fires created event for that things , Thanks for your answer anyway I appriciate this.

Comment: It is possible that you could combine a delete event with a create event, and manage a cache of which files are changing.

Comment: Billiard files per second being changed (in my machine at-least).
Managing a cache would be bad resources wise :(.
Maybe there is a way to know if the changes was being made by user directly.

Comment: The watcher is too low level hook :(.
obviously it hooks `onZwCreate` etc events.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can filter by users. You may want to just monitor a directory that doesn't include the OS folders and files.

Comment: Yeah that what I came up with , before asking the question here as well :( ... it seems kinda hole in NT . :(

Comment: mmmhmm ... when I right clicking on file -> some Event get fired , then when I click copy or paste or cut there should be another events fired -> is it possible to hook it ?(in this case I can easy manage the cache to know from where to where ).

Comment: I think a Deleted event would be raised for the directory that the file is copied from, and then the Created event would be raised for the new directory it is being copied to.

Comment: I thought about selected file event , and then to make some comparisons between selected file , and deleted/created events.
But I didn't count 1 thing -> user can select 3k files at once :(

Comment: Also delete event won't fire for directory file copied from , only create event in directory copied to , the delete event will behave this way only if the file was cut.